# Error using ImportJSONBasicAuth to get data from my Bank API into Google Sheet

Tags: api, rest, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula, bank

I am trying to get my bank balances in Google Sheets and decided to use this script https://github.com/bradjasper/ImportJSON to pull data from my Investec bank account via the API here: https://developer.investec.com/programmable-banking/#authorization

I am calling the function `ImportJSONBasicAuth("https://openapi.investec.com/identity/v2/oauth2/token","{username}","{secret}","","")` with my username and secret, in my Google Sheet... But I get an error as follows

> Error Exception: Request failed for https://openapi.investec.com returned code 400 (line 220).

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

---

EDIT

Digging a little deeper into the error...

This is the function I'm calling

```
function ImportJSONBasicAuth(url, username, password, query, parseOptions) {
  var encodedAuthInformation = Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password);
  var header = {headers: {Authorization: "Basic " + encodedAuthInformation}};
  return ImportJSONAdvanced(url, header, query, parseOptions, includeXPath_, defaultTransform_);
}
```

Which calls this function in turn - which has the line producing the error i.e. line 220 commented below

```
function ImportJSONAdvanced(url, fetchOptions, query, parseOptions, includeFunc, transformFunc) {
  var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, fetchOptions);  //line 220
  var object   = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText());
  
  return parseJSONObject_(object, query, parseOptions, includeFunc, transformFunc);
}
```

---

I found a function `ImportJSONViaPost` in the code, so I tried to combine that with the function `ImportJSONBasicAuth`  that I was using, but also get the same error.

Here is the combined function:

```js
function ImportJSONBasicAuthViaPost(url, username, password, payload, fetchOptions, query, parseOptions) {
  var postOptions = parseToObject_(fetchOptions);

  var encodedAuthInformation = Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password);
  var APIKey = "Basic " + encodedAuthInformation;

  if (postOptions["headers.Authorization"] == null) {
    postOptions["headers.Authorization"] = APIKey;
  }

  if (postOptions["method"] == null) {
    postOptions["method"] = "POST";
  }

  if (postOptions["payload"] == null) {
    postOptions["payload"] = payload;
  }

  if (postOptions["contentType"] == null) {
    postOptions["contentType"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  }

  if (postOptions["contentType"] == null) {
    postOptions["contentType"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  }

  convertToBool_(postOptions, "validateHttpsCertificates");
  convertToBool_(postOptions, "useIntranet");
  convertToBool_(postOptions, "followRedirects");
  convertToBool_(postOptions, "muteHttpExceptions");

  return ImportJSONAdvanced(url, postOptions, query, parseOptions, includeXPath_, defaultTransform_);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  const headers = {
    'Authorization': `Basic ${APIKey}`
  };
  const payload = {
   'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
   'scope': 'accounts'
  }
  const options = {
    'method': 'POST',
    'payload': payload,
    'headers': headers
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I really appreciate it. Unfortunately I am still getting the same error. 

I found a function `ImportJSONViaPost` in the code, so I tried to combine that with the function `ImportJSONBasicAuth ` that I was using, but also get the same error. 

I will add the code as an answer below because there is a character limit on comments.

Comment: Updated. If it does not work I have no idea.

Comment: Thank you! This works if I use `const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://openapi.investec.com/identity/v2/oauth2/token', options);` so now I just have to hook that up to importing the data to sheet :)

How can I thank you more!?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer from @idfurw and rewriting the `ImportJSONViaPost` function I managed to create a function that gets the Basic Auth information from POST to import to my Google Sheet :)

```
/**
 * Helper function to authenticate with basic auth informations and import a JSON feed via a POST request. 
 * Returns the results to be inserted into a Google Spreadsheet. 
 * The JSON feed is flattened to create a two-dimensional array. 
 * The first row contains the headers, with each column header indicating the path to 
 * that data in the JSON feed. The remaining rows contain the data.
 *
 * To retrieve the JSON, a POST request is sent to the URL and the payload is passed as the content of the request using the content 
 * type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If the fetchOptions define a value for "method", "payload" or "contentType", these 
 * values will take precedent. For example, advanced users can use this to make this function pass XML as the payload using a GET 
 * request and a content type of "application/xml; charset=utf-8". For more information on the available fetch options, see
 * https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app . At this time the "headers" option is not supported.
 * 
 * By default, the returned data gets transformed so it looks more like a normal data import. Specifically:
 *
 *   - Data from parent JSON elements gets inherited to their child elements, so rows representing child elements contain the values 
 *     of the rows representing their parent elements.
 *   - Values longer than 256 characters get truncated.
 *   - Headers have slashes converted to spaces, common prefixes removed and the resulting text converted to title case. 
 *
 * To change this behavior, pass in one of these values in the options parameter:
 *
 *    noInherit:     Don't inherit values from parent elements
 *    noTruncate:    Don't truncate values
 *    rawHeaders:    Don't prettify headers
 *    noHeaders:     Don't include headers, only the data
 *    allHeaders:    Include all headers from the query parameter in the order they are listed
 *    debugLocation: Prepend each value with the row & column it belongs in
 *
 * For example:
 *
 *   =ImportJSON("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?v=2&alt=json", "user=bob&apikey=xxxx", 
 *               "validateHttpsCertificates=false", "/feed/entry/title,/feed/entry/content", "noInherit,noTruncate,rawHeaders")
 * 
 * @param {url}          the URL to a public JSON feed
 * @param {username}     the Username for authentication
 * @param {password}     the Password for authentication
 * @param {payload}      the content to pass with the POST request; usually a URL encoded list of parameters separated by ampersands
 * @param {fetchOptions} a comma-separated list of options used to retrieve the JSON feed from the URL
 * @param {query}        a comma-separated list of paths to import. Any path starting with one of these paths gets imported.
 * @param {parseOptions} a comma-separated list of options that alter processing of the data
 * @customfunction
 *
 * @return a two-dimensional array containing the data, with the first row containing headers
 **/

function ImportJSONBasicAuthViaPost(url, username, password, payload, fetchOptions, query, parseOptions) {
  var postOptions = parseToObject_(fetchOptions);

  var APIKey = Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password);

  const headers = {
    'Authorization': `Basic ${APIKey}`
  };

  if (postOptions["headers"] == null) {
    postOptions["headers"] = headers;
  }
  
  if (postOptions["method"] == null) {
    postOptions["method"] = "POST";
  }

  if (postOptions["payload"] == null) {
    postOptions["payload"] = payload;
  }

  if (postOptions["contentType"] == null) {
    postOptions["contentType"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
  }

  convertToBool_(postOptions, "validateHttpsCertificates");
  convertToBool_(postOptions, "useIntranet");
  convertToBool_(postOptions, "followRedirects");
  convertToBool_(postOptions, "muteHttpExceptions");
  
  return ImportJSONAdvanced(url, postOptions, query, parseOptions, includeXPath_, defaultTransform_);
}
```